# how to save values to a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to save values to a list, but when I do it so it gives me None value. Not sure what exactly am I doing wrong here

```
for sentence in mylist:
    global typ, DN, pn
    matches = re.finditer(regex_f, sentence, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        subst = sentence[match.end():]
        pn_matches = re.findall(regexp, subst, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

        if len(pn_matches) > 0:
            pn = pn_matches
            pn_p = ("{pn}".format(flansch=match.group(), pn=pn))
            print(pn)
            list_test = []
            dat_test = list_test.append(pn)
            print(dat_test)

        else:
            pn_p = '?'
            print("no PN found".format(flansch=match.group()))

['PN10']
None
['PN16']
None
['PN 40']
None
```

If I print values directly from pn its working, but when I append it to a list it says None.

Comment: Appending to a list doesn't return: it changes the list *in-place*.

Comment: You should use append like this ```list_test.append(pn)``` without adding it to a new variable. Then if you ```print(list_test)```  instead of ```print(dat_test)``` you should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others already said `list.append()` has no return value. Thats why `dat_test` will always be set to `None`.

You should use append like this `list_test.append(pn)` without adding it to a new variable. Then if you `print(list_test)` instead of `print(dat_test)` you should be fine.

```
for sentence in mylist:
    global typ, DN, pn
    matches = re.finditer(regex_f, sentence, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        subst = sentence[match.end():]
        pn_matches = re.findall(regexp, subst, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

        if len(pn_matches) > 0:
            pn = pn_matches
            pn_p = ("{pn}".format(flansch=match.group(), pn=pn))
            print(pn)
            list_test = []
            list_test.append(pn)
            print(list_test)

        else:
            pn_p = '?'
            print("no PN found".format(flansch=match.group()))
```

Depending on what your real use case is I would suggest to think about the placement of `list_test` in your code as it is always reseted to an empty list for each sentence where `len(pn_matches) > 0`. You will end up with only the last result beeing in the list!

EDIT:

```
list_test = []
for sentence in mylist:
    global typ, DN, pn
    matches = re.finditer(regex_f, sentence, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        subst = sentence[match.end():]
        pn_matches = re.findall(regexp, subst, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

        if len(pn_matches) > 0:
            pn = pn_matches
            pn_p = ("{pn}".format(flansch=match.group(), pn=pn))
            print(pn)

            list_test.append(pn)
            print(list_test)

        else:
            pn_p = '?'
            print("no PN found".format(flansch=match.group()))
```

Comment: That works, question is how do I make list_test global ? I defined like: global list_test

Comment: @Nithish if you put it outside of your ```for``` loop it will keep all results. Meaning in the first line of your code snippet. Second line will be ```for sentence in mylist:``` But don´t forget to remove it from the inside then! See my code after "EDIT:". If I answered your question I would be happy if you accept my answer as the correct one. :-)

Comment: print(*list_test, *list_test_TYP, *list_test_DN)  =  ['PN10'] ['PN16'] ['PN 40'] ['Typ 11'] ['Typ 11'] ['Typ 12'] ['DN600'] ['DN800'] How do I merge lists like ['PN10'] ['Typ 11']  ['DN800']

Comment: You can simply add lists like this ```final_list = list1 + list2 + list3```